# Java Threads: Figure out which threads are still running

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

For debugging purposes, I want to figure out which threads of my program are still running. There's seems to be one or more threads that accidentally were not interrupted. Some sort of nice printable format would be a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is your friend for this kind of debugging.  It's in the /bin directory of your JDK install.  Shows all of the threads as a graph view and allows you to drill down into what they're doing.  The `Thread Dump` button will print out all of their current stack traces so you can see if something is stuck somewhere in your user code.

Comment: +1 JVisualVM is a great tool. I prefer JConsole for examining individual threads, but the Thread Dump feature of JVisualVM is great. I wish it dumped it to a display that allowed for text searching/highlighting though.

Comment: I use fgrep for finding text. Eg jstack <PID> |  fgrep "com.bla.foo"

Comment: You can still dump the threads in jconsole via the jmx control

Answer (score 5):

Use 'jps' command line tool to see active java processes and jstack  for showing active threads.

[jstack doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html)

[example](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-JVM-Thread-Dump-Stack-Strace.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a programmatic solution, something like this (in JDK 1.5 or later) should work:

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> stack = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
for (Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : stack.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Thread named '" + 
                       entry.getKey().getName() + 
                       "' is alive");
}
```

Comment: +1 for java implementation (I didn't know that this is possible)

Comment: Psst, you could just iterate through `stack.keySet()` rather than taking the `Entrys` and ignoring the value.  It does exactly the same as what you have, but in my mind it's clearer (no feeling that you *must* be using the value somewhere...).

Answer (score 1):

Following nogudnik's answer, tempus-fugit has a programmatic thread dump (and deadlock detection) feature, see http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/threading/dumps/

Comment: +1 to your answer and +100000 to *tempus-fugit*.  Besides the amazingly retarded project name this obviously is **very** convenient :)

Answer (score 0):

"There's seems to be one or more threads that accidentally were not interrupted".  I wound't say things weren't interrupted.  Calling Thread.interrupt() doesn't force a runnable to stop.  It sets the interrupt flag, and possibly causes blocking operations (like a Thread.sleep or java.nio calls) to throw either an InterruptedException or some other exception (like ClosedByInterruptException for nio).  Your runnables have to check Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() and behave nicely.